# What is best practice of Creating multiple Classes or Using Switch statment for Class Version Control

Tags: oop, design-patterns

In my project , I have to maintain Version of Classes. so There are two approach I can go with

```
 1) Edit Same Class with Version and Use Switch Case for maintain older version

    Pro : 
    1) We only have to create one single class  
    2) If you want to used old version class attribute which are now not supported in
       current version of class so you just provide them Default Values.

    Cons:
    1) There may be possibility that some attribute are not used now but they still
       present in Class for supporting older version
    2) It also break Open Closed Principle
```

Next Approach:

```
 2) Create new classes for each version and maintain them by using any design pattern 
   so for example I have Base Class = BaseClass and It have multiple Derived classes 
   like DerivedClass1,DerevivedClass2. Each class have different version.

   Pro:
   1) If now we want to use old version class so we not have to worry about its 
   attribute behavior  because we will fetch DerivedClass1 for Version 1 ,    
   DerivedClass2 for Version 2
   2) We will put all common property in Base class so Derived class will only have 
    extended property.
   3) We also follow Open Closed Principle

   Cons: 
   1) We need to create new classes for all new versions.
```

So, I would like to know your views on it , Please let me know if you required more clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your questions usually depends on how versioning classes are going to be used:

- If they are containers for data like [poco](/questions/tagged/poco) or [pojo](/questions/tagged/pojo), take a look at **Adapter** and **Layer of Indirection** patterns and [soa](/questions/tagged/soa) examples. Especially how [servicebus](/questions/tagged/servicebus) handles different versions of web services or databases at same time.
- If they are containers for different versions of algorithms, then [inheritance](/questions/tagged/inheritance) or[composition](/questions/tagged/composition), **Abstract factory** pattern and may [oop](/questions/tagged/oop) be with you!

For me, your first proposal to put all eggs in one class, and configure it with attributes, sound like nightmare and not worth the time spent.